# How do search a value from multiple valueNames in registry key using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have multiple registry values names each with a value under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\HomeApp`. Now I want to search for a specific value from a list of registry valuesnames with each containing a value. I have:

```
VALUENAME     VALUE    
valuename0    98OTIUO    
valuename1    H989804    
valuename2    KG65326    
valuename3    BCG37A2    
...
```

Suppose I want to find if there is value "KG65326" how do I do that in vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to iterate through all the value entries until you find the one with the specific value. You'll be able to do this by using a `For`-loop on the array returned from [**`RegistryKey.GetValueNames()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluenames(v=vs.110).aspx), and then get the value for each entry via [**`RegistryKey.GetValue()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1(v=vs.110).aspx).

You could simply make an extension for it:

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function ContainsValue(ByVal RegKey As RegistryKey, ByVal Value As Object) As Boolean
        For Each ValueName As String In RegKey.GetValueNames()
            If RegKey.GetValue(ValueName) = Value Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next

        Return False
    End Function
End Module
```

**Example usage:**

```
Using MyKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("HomeApp")
    If MyKey.ContainsValue("KG65326") = True Then
        'Do your stuff here.
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Vincent. Works perfectly well.

Comment: @Chata : No problem, I'm glad it worked! I have not yet had the chance to test it. :)