# VB.net - Search the whole registry for a value only?

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to make a programm that searches the WHOLE registry for one specific value WITHOUT declaring the location of the key. It should just search for the value and print it in a msg box but the only way I found was to declare the location and search for the key then. The code should also take the value of a text box and search for this specific value. I don't really know what I could possible do next so I'm trying to get some help from you guys. If you have snippets, articels or smth like that pls send it 2 me :)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try again with a more specific question that we can answer.

Comment: Yeah, thats why I asked if someone has an Article or any information on how to do this since I already searched google up for it and haven't found anything.

Comment: Re questing off site resources like links, tutorials or libraries is *also* Off-Topic.  All spelled out in [Ask], the [faq].  Also please take the [Tour]

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38492722/3740093